# Int set to 0 but displaying nil

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a variable in private interface

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    int age;
}
```

and in viewDidLoad method if i assign it 0 and put a breakpoint after this line. If i use

```
po age
```

it display  instead of 0. Why?

Comment: The `po` command in lldb `prints` an `object` — `0` can be interpreted as a `nil` object pointer. Use `p` to `print` the value itself.